# Azure Application Web Service Logout

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-web-app-service

So what happened is i deployed two azure web app in Azure Web App service (Frontend and Backend). Then I set-up both authenticated by Azure Active Directory.

Now, In the browser when I login via frontend, I can access both frontend and Backend. However, when I logout in frontend using '.auth/logout' I can still access the Backend?

Any idea about this ?

Comment: Authentication cookie is still valid for the other domain? You logged out of front-end app + AAD but not the back-end app. I don't think the "Easy auth" allows remote sign-out.

Comment: But I only login using the front-end. It's just sad that in the browser it doesn't logout all apps when it can access all app by logging-in just one.